# Access was denied by the external data source. The following connections failed to refresh: "data connection name"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

I created an Excel report in Excel 2013 with a data-source as SQL stored procedure. I deployed this Excel report to Trusted Excel Library. I have done all configurations correctly in Excel Service Application in Central Admin 2013.

On opening this report I encounter below exception:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh369968(v=office.14).aspx

although meant for 2010 I think you might find a lot of use in checking this out. I just encountered this problem and found that I needed to use an SSID with the secure store service because of the authentication mode used by my web app. hope this helps!

Comment: Haley, you got it right... After using SSID... A few configuration step in Excel 2013.. the above issue got resolved...